# Parse query innerQuery with relation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

im trying to make a query like the one blow, but since i can't test it, i would like to know your opinion about if it would work:

"PencilCase" is a table that contains different pencils:
"objectId" - "name" - "createdAt" - ....

"Students" is a table that contains students and specifically a column of a relation of "PencilCase" objects in it.

So if i query for students i wouldn't get the pencilCase objects by default because its a relation, i would have to query for it after.

Now that i have explained it, i want to query for "Students" but i want to limit it by its "PencilCase", so i want to know if the query below would get the job done:

```
var Class = Parse.Object.extend("PencilCase");
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Class);
innerQuery.containsAll("objectId", arrayOfDesiredPensilCases);

var Class = Parse.Object.extend("Students");
var query = new Parse.Query(Class);
query.matchesQuery("pencils", innerQuery);
query.find({
success: function(students) {
        //
    }
});
```

Thanks,
Newton

Answer (score 1):

Parse provided a very similar scenario that I think it will work for you as well:

```
var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");
var Comment = Parse.Object.extend("Comment");
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Post);
innerQuery.exists("image");
var query = new Parse.Query(Comment);
query.matchesQuery("post", innerQuery);
query.find({
  success: function(comments) {
    // comments now contains the comments for posts with images.
  }
});
```

Comment: I know, I have read the docs and have see this.. but the difference is that my example has the innerQuery in a field of type relation.. thats where my concern is.